# Pass clicked item in list generated from array in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, parameter-passing

I'm developing a web app using ReactJS and Material-UI. While I was able to generate a list of Ride objects from an array (`offeredRides`), I want to be able to click on any given item in the list and pass that specific list item into the `handleClickOpen()` method so the opened dialog box could display information based on which list item was clicked. I came to realize that the `offeredRide` variable seems to be the iterator used to create the list from the array in a "for each" sort of manner. I originally thought that this variable would be able to represent a specific instance (in this case, list item), and could be used to pass the clicked list item into the `handleClickOpen()` method, but it seems much more generic than that, or at least only seems to be involved in the generation of the list. What am I missing? I think including a key property for each item is part of the issue, but do I need to change the structure of the Ride class as well? Thanks in advance for the help.

**driver-page.js**

```
`import OfferDetailsDialog from '../components/offer-details-dialog';
...
<List dense={this.state.dense}>
  {this.state.offeredRides.map((offeredRide) => {
    return (
      <ListItem
        button
        onClick={() => { this.offerDetailsDialogChild.handleClickOpen(); }}
        disableGutters={this.state.noGutters}
        divider={this.state.divider}
      >
...
<OfferDetailsDialog ref={(offerDetailsDialogInstance) => { this.offerDetailsDialogChild = offerDetailsDialogInstance; }} />`
```

**offer-details-dialog.js**

```
`// Open the add offer dialog
handleClickOpen = (offeredRide) => {
  this.setState({ ride: offeredRide });
  this.setState({ display: true });
};`
```

**ride-model.js**

```
`/**
 * Contains data on rides which may be offers or rides
 */
class RideModel {
  constructor(origin, destination, date, driver) {
    this.origin = origin;
    this.destination = destination;
    this.date = date;
    this.driver = driver;
  }`

  `origin;
  destination;`

  `date; // Date`

  `driver; // User - the driver for the ride
  passengers = []; // Users - any users who are part of the ride
  maxCapacity; // The number of seats available when the ride offer is created 
  pendingRequests = []; // Requests - request objects from users who wish to join the ride`

  `// Determine whether a user is in the list of passengers
  isUserAPassenger = (user) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.passengers.length; i++) {
      if (this.passengers[i] === user) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}`

`export default RideModel;`
```

Comment: 1. Are you not using redux with this?                                                        2. Is offer-details-dialog.js a component?

Comment: @Akhileshkrishnan I'm not, and yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  withRouter,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      offeredRides: [
        {
          id: 0,
          offerer: "Person 1",
          details: "this is a ride to sf"
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          offerer: "Person 2",
          details: "this is a ride to LA"
        }
      ],
      openedRide: ""
    };
  }
  open = id => {
    this.setState({ openedRide: id });
  };
  render() {
    const { offeredRides, openedRide } = this.state;
    const filteredRides = offeredRides.filter(item => item.id === openedRide);
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Route
              exact
              path={"/"}
              render={() => (
                <RidesPage
                  open={this.open}
                  offeredRides={this.state.offeredRides}
                />
              )}
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path={`/ride/:id`}
              render={() => (
                <Ride
                  open={this.open}
                  filteredRides={filteredRides}
                  offeredRides={offeredRides}
                  openedRide={this.state.openedRide}
                />
              )}
            />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
App.contextTypes = {
  router: PropTypes.object
};

const RidesPage = props => (
  <div>
    {props.offeredRides.map(item => (
      <div>
        {" "}
        offerer:{item.offerer} details: {item.details}{" "}
        <Link to={`ride/${item.id}`}>
          {" "}
          <button onClick={() => props.open(item.id)}> View Ride</button>{" "}
        </Link>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);

const Ride = props => { 
  const filt = props.offeredRides.filter(item => item.id === props.openedRide);
  return (
    <div>
      hello
      {filt ? (
        <div> {filt.map(item => <div> {item.offerer} </div>)} </div>
      ) : (
        <div> Loading </div>
      )}{" "}
    </div>
  );
};

render(
  App,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: let me know if you still need help with this